# Put an encrypted password in my chart, break the responsive view codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Since I added an encrypted password, when my program shows all information stored in my database table, the table inside my view file is not longer responsive. I think it is because the encrypted password is too longer.. but i do not know how should i solve this

Take a look:

[image]

Here is my view file:

```
        <?php include('header.php'); ?>

    <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('../resources/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('../resources/css/bootstrap.css'); ?>"/>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <h2 align="center">TABLE:USER</h2>

                <a href="<?php echo site_url('login/add') ?>">ADD</a>
                <table class="table table-hover" align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" id="tabla_busqueda">
                    <thead>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>User</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Lastname</th>
                        <th>Password</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                    </thead>


    <tbody>

    <?php

        if (count($records) > 0 && $records != false)
         { 

            foreach($records as $record) {
            echo "<tr> 
        <td>".$record['id']."</td> 
        <td>".$record['username']."</td> 
        <td>".$record['name']."</td> 
        <td>".$record['lastname']."</td> 
        <td>".$record['password']."</td> 
        <td>".$record['type']."</td> 
        <td>".$record['status']."</td> 
        <td>".$record['date']."</td> 

        </tr>"; 

        }
        }


    ?>

    </tbody>


        </table>

            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Hope you can help me..

Comment: I got to mate, i am the admin user and gotta show that :S @KirkBeard

Comment: What reason is there for an admin to know it? It's not like you can do anything with it. You can't even tell that it's not empty.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would avoid using tables, especially when you seem to be wanting to use Bootstrap to get responsive layouts. As for the encrypted password, the table is doing it's job (expanding cols to the correct size).

I don't understand what you want to accomplish, nor what the problem is. But if you just want a more narrow column, I'd suggest using [substr](http://php.net/substr) to shorten and then maybe adding a "copy to clipboard" functionality next to the shortened string. For example [clipboardjs](https://clipboardjs.com/). Just a suggestion.

Comment: This is a comment, not answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to add comments. Sorry.

Comment: [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) and as it stands now you'll start losing ground if folks decide to down-vote this.